# Problem with data from subscriber not going anywhere

Tags: ros, std-msgs, sensor-msgs, msg-subscriber

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related question: https://answers.ros.org/question/278181/issues-with-seg-faults-and-node-not-publishing-anything/

In my code there are two subscriber functions. I want to pass the shared pointer data to other data defined in my file. My code is below:

```
    std::vector<double> imu_, euler_t;
    ros::Publisher escs_pub;

    ros::Subscriber imu_sub;
    ros::Subscriber DOF_sub;
    double I_cm_xx, I_cm_yy, I_cm_zz, P_q, P_w;

    void KeyboardCallback(const maple::Euler_Thrust::ConstPtr& msg){
        euler_t.clear();
        euler_t.resize(4);
        euler_t.push_back((msg->psi)*3.14159265359/180);
        euler_t.push_back((msg->phi)*3.14159265359/180);
        euler_t.push_back((msg->theta)*3.14159265359/180);
        euler_t.push_back(msg->thrust);
    }

    void imuCallback(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr &imu) {
        imu_.clear();
        imu_.resize(7);
        imu_.push_back(imu->orientation.x); 
        imu_.push_back(imu->orientation.y); 
        imu_.push_back(imu->orientation.z); 
        imu_.push_back(imu->orientation.w);
        imu_.push_back(imu->angular_velocity.x);
        imu_.push_back(imu->angular_velocity.y);
        imu_.push_back(imu->angular_velocity.z);
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv){
        ros::init(argc, argv, "P_2");
            ros::NodeHandle nh;
            ros::NodeHandle pnh("~");
            pnh.param("I_cm_xx", I_cm_xx, 0.0118);
            pnh.param("I_cm_yy", I_cm_yy, 0.0118);
            pnh.param("I_cm_zz", I_cm_zz, 0.0181);
            pnh.param("P_q", P_q, 2.27);
            pnh.param("P_w", P_w, 0.85);
        while(ros::ok()){
    ROS_INFO("oy1");
            escs_pub = nh.advertise<maple::ESCs>("ESCs",1);
            DOF_sub = nh.subscribe("KeyboardTeleop", 1, KeyboardCallback);
            imu_sub = nh.subscribe("imu", 1, imuCallback);
            my_pkg::std_msg msg;

            double q_ref_w = cos(euler_t[0]/2)*cos(euler_t[1]/2)*cos(euler_t[2]/2); //THIS IS WHERE THE SEGMENTATION FAULT OCCURS, BECAUSE THE EULER_T VECTOR IS EMPTY OR UNPOPULATED!!!!!!

                  //more math  

            escs_pub.publish(msg);
            ros::spin();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I'm so lost... When excluding any operations with the vectors doing ROS_INFO inside the subscriber functions shows that they do indeed get the data too. I made this code as simple as it can be and it's still not working. I have a feeling it's a problem with the vectors not being passed the values in the right order and I tried that but nothing works. Please, any help would be massively appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278225/problem-with-data-from-subscriber-not-going-anywhere/) by [hanjuku-joshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31824/hanjuku-joshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few issues here (some of which you could probably avoid if you go through the ROS tutorials carefully ;) )

- Advertise and subscribe should be
  done outside the while loop as otherwise publishers and subscribers get re-initalized every time.
- When running a `while ros::ok()` loop, you should call `ros::spinOnce()` instead of `spin()` as the latter is a blocking call.
- The `euler_t` vector only gets resized in the subscriber callback. As  callbacks only get serviced when a `spin` (or `spinOnce`, see above) has been called, it is perfectly normal that your code trying to access elements of the vector crashes.
- Even if you would call spin correctly, there is no guarantee that the callback filling `euler_t` is called before you try accessing elements of it in the while-loop. For this reason (and many others) it's a good idea to check if the vector really has the correct size before trying to access it's elements directly.
- Instead of filling vectors in the callbacks you could also store the shared pointer to the last received message and then check if that one is non-zero wherever you try to use the data.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hanjuku-joshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31824/hanjuku-joshi/) on 2017-12-27**:
Excellent advice. I actually just ended up solving the problem using arrays instead of vectors, but you certainly have me plenty information and advice to work on for the future. Legend :D